# MySQL and regexp - return as a SELECT column with a table's column's regexp matching part only

Tags: mysql, regex

I know there is an easy way to give a WHERE condition matching a regexp in MySQL, but my question is different. The column is like this:

```
jknewfjnkewnjkfewnjfwe1jnkf2jnw wefwef 1234567.12345678 qwrqwerqwrq
jnewdnkewjk ewnfewf1 wefwefew2 1234568.22314152 qwrqwrqwr qw
whjefjwefwe1 wefwefwef2 qweqwrqrw 1234369.21213131 qwdqwdqwd
```

I would like to get a SELECT column SUBSTRING phrase, which returns for me:

```
selectcol1  selectcol2
1234567     12345678
1234568     22314152
1234369     21213131
```

All I know: first matching number is 7 digits, and 2nd matching number is 8 digits always, and the parts before and after surely won't match the exactly 7 digit pattern.

Is there any way to get these SELECT columns?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  No.  Long answer...

```
REGEXP '[[:<:]][0-9]{7}[[:>:]].*[[:<:]][0-9]{8}[[:>:]]'
```

will match the first 'word' of 7 digits followed (eventually) by a 'word' with 8 digits.

Demonstration (1=true):

```
mysql> SELECT 'jnewdnkewjk ewnfewf1 wefwefew2 1234568.22314152 qwrqwrqwr qw'
    ->        REGEXP '[[:<:]][0-9]{7}[[:>:]].*[[:<:]][0-9]{8}[[:>:]]' AS test;
+------+
| test |
+------+
|    1 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Keep in mind that SQL is not a good language for *extracting* those fields.  In fact, I would say that you should use PHP (or other language) to *extract* the fields *after* MySQL locates and fetches the *rows*.

That is, there is no `LOCATE()` with regexp.

Comment: If it was used commonly, I'd use an algorithmical language anyway, but in this case it was just "runonce reporting laziness", so in this case performance wouldn't matter anyway. (I also know, storing MySQL columns like this is bad, but this database was not designed by me)